# Saving an EF object passed by reference with .SaveChanges()

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Problem:

I can make changes to object after pulling it from the Database, howerver, I cannot save the object via Context.SaveChanges() method.

Already Tried:

Adding a modified tracker to the object (Gives an error), Reading articles about using the SaveChanges method, Saving immediately after making changes.

Possible Problems:

Object is being passed by ref to several functions.

I normally do not have a problem with EF, but I'm using a lot of reflection here. I am adding an undo button to a rather large program that needs to look back on the object. When undo is clicked, the actual object is pulled, tested against the 'after object', and if they match, then a function figures out what property value changed, and sets the value from the before object. Then Saves changes and should update the database.

Here is some code:

Public Sub UndoRedoAction(IdNow As Integer)
        Dim Db As New Luk_StackUp_ProgramEntities

```
    'First we need to find the object in the list given the id in UndoRedoLog
    Dim ObjectNow As ClsUndoRedoItem

    Try

        ObjectNow = (From a In UndoRedoLog Where a.ID = IdNow).SingleOrDefault

    Catch ex As Exception   'Fail

        ObjectNow = Nothing
        MsgBox("Could not find the item. Either does not exist or there is multiple with same id.  " + ex.ToString)

        Exit Sub
    End Try

    'Is this a new object?
    If ObjectNow.ID = -1 Then

        MsgBox("This object does not exist yet")

    End If

    'See if after object is the same as the object in the database
    Dim ActualObject As Object = ""

    'if this is a redo object, don't check since all of that has already been done
    If ObjectNow.WhatGroupChanged.isRedo = True Then

        GetDataBaseObject(ObjectNow.AfterObject, ActualObject)

    Else

        Try 'Pass the after object since that is the object that should be stored in Db
            Call TestActualObject(ObjectNow.AfterObject, ActualObject)

        Catch ex As Exception   'Fail
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End If

    'Now set the actaul object to before if it is not null
    If Not (ActualObject Is Nothing) Then

        Try 'Set to the before object

            'Need to find change and set that value
            SetChangedProperties(ActualObject, ObjectNow.BeforeObject)
            Db.Entry(ActualObject).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Failed

            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Exit Sub
        End Try

    ElseIf ObjectNow.WhatGroupChanged.isRedo Then   'For redo objects only

        'Dont allow, does not match what is in the database
        MsgBox("Cannot Redo object")

        'Remove from list
        UndoRedoLog.Remove(ObjectNow)

        Exit Sub
    Else

        'Dont allow, does not match what is in the database
        MsgBox("Cannot Undo object")

        'Remove from list
        UndoRedoLog.Remove(ObjectNow)
        Exit Sub

    End If

    'Switch list
    ObjectNow.WhatGroupChanged.isRedo = Not (ObjectNow.WhatGroupChanged.isRedo)

    'switch the before and after objects
    Dim TempObject As Object = CopyObject(ObjectNow.BeforeObject)
    ObjectNow.BeforeObject = CopyObject(ObjectNow.AfterObject)
    ObjectNow.AfterObject = CopyObject(TempObject)

    'Set the id higher up on the list
    GlobalCounter.ObjectCounter += 1
    ObjectNow.ID = GlobalCounter.ObjectCounter

    'Now save changes
    Db.SaveChanges()
```

This code:`Db.Entry(ActualObject).State = Entity.EntityState.Modified`
 is what i tried in order to fix, but now it gives an errors. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: "but now it gives an error" What error does it give?

Comment: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to save it with a different DbContext than the one that got it from the database. Perhaps you disposed of one before you started doing all the reflection?

Comment: Ahh that kinda makes sense. Is it possible to pass a context as a parameter? Maybe I need to send the correct context in order to save it to that one

Comment: It's always possible to pass anything as a parameter. But, it all depends on where the code is being called from, and that type of architecture is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so thanks to @krillgar I have figured out what was wrong. I was declaring multiple contexts and trying to save to the wrong one. So solution was to combine my functions into one, just to make sure i was doing everything within one context. So now my function declares a new context, gets the object from its respective data table, does all of my checks, sets the value back, and saves all in one function. Simple as that!